# Swift warning in Xcode 14 : Method confirm(intent:) conflicts with method confirm(intent:completion:) with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14

Testing the new widget for iOS 16 with Xcode 14, I'm facing an issue trying to port the iOS 14 widget with the new WidgetFamily like .accessoryInline or .accessoryRectangular.

After adding conditional macros to solve some errors in order to build for watchOS and iOS (cf Apple WWDC 22 video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10050/), Xcode display no red errors but yellow blocking warnings:

> Method 'confirm(intent:)' with Objective-C selector
> 'confirmConfiguration:completion:' conflicts with method
> 'confirm(intent:completion:)' with the same Objective-C selector; this
> is an error in Swift 6

[image]
Any idea how to solve it?

EDITED : Finally works without fix that, see answer below. But I'm still interesting to remove this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it passed without fixing this warning. I remove the last errors around the extension bundle name (has to be prefixed with the watch app bundle and follow by ".xxxxxx" of your choice without any further dot). I also had a "4" (Apple Watch) value to "Targeted Device Families" in build settings (was previously "1,2" for iPhone, iPad).